# Autodialling app that allows timed selection of phone line menu options

Tags: applications, automation, phone-app

I have searched the Google Play store with a number of likely terms to find this, and Googled also, only to find "simplistic" options for auto dialling.

Am trying to get through to a government department that allows call backs, but don't just want to select the number at a pre-determined interval from the last call (to give their system a chance to clear some of those call backs), something I can relatively easily do myself, it would be most helpful to have dialpad numbers sent down the line at predetermined times once the phone connects, so I don't have to wait to be able to select each of them.

This seems like it would be the most programmatically simple part of a auto dialler app. Does an app to do this really not exist for Android?

Answer (score 0):

Seems one needs to search for "meeting auto dialers" to find the (as of writing this) only result https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.technochakra.meetingautodialer&hl=en_US

Alas the aforementioned app doesn't do auto redialing, and in the reviews from some years ago there doesn't appear to be great interest from the developer to implement this, instead suggesting the use of https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.llamalab.automate to launch widgets of templates in the Meeting Auto Dialer app that can be added to one's home screen.